# Recursively wrapping method invocations with compiler plugins/macros

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-compiler, scala-quasiquotes, scala-macro-paradise

## OUTLINE

I have an API that looks something like this:

```
package com.example

object ExternalApi {

  def create[T <: SpecialElement](elem: T): TypeConstructor[T] =
    TypeConstructor(elem)

  def create1[T <: SpecialElement](elem: T): TypeConstructor[T] =
    TypeConstructor(elem)

  def create2[T <: SpecialElement](elem: T): TypeConstructor[T] =
    TypeConstructor(elem)
  //...

}

object MyApi {

  def process[T <: TypeConstructor[_ <: SpecialElement]](
      l: T,
      metadata: List[String]): T = {
    println("I've been called!")
    //do some interesting stuff with the List's type parameter here
    l
  }

}

case class TypeConstructor[E](elem: E)

trait SpecialElement
```

The `ExternalApi` (which is **actually external** to my lib, so no modifying that) has a series of calls that I'd like to automatically wrap with `MyApi.process` calls, with the `metadata` argument derived from the final type of `T`.

To illustrate, the calls to be wrapped could have any form, including nested calls, and calls within other AST subtree types (such as `Block`s), e.g. :

```
package com.example.test

import com.example.{ExternalApi, SpecialElement}

object ApiPluginTest extends App {
  //one possible form
  val targetList = ExternalApi.create(Blah("name"))

  //and another
  ExternalApi.create2(ExternalApi.create1(Blah("sth")).elem)

  //and yet another
  val t = {

    val sub1 = ExternalApi.create(Blah("anything"))

    val sub2 = ExternalApi.create1(sub1.elem)

    sub2
  }

}

case class Blah(name: String) extends SpecialElement
```

Since compiler plugins handle matching structures within ASTs recursively "for free", I've decided to go with them.

However, due to the fact that I need to match **a specific type signature**, the plugin follows the `typer` phase.

Here's the code of the `PluginComponent`:

```
package com.example.plugin

import com.example.{SpecialElement, TypeConstructor}

import scala.tools.nsc.Global
import scala.tools.nsc.plugins.PluginComponent
import scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform

class WrapInApiCallComponent(val global: Global)
    extends PluginComponent
    with Transform {
  protected def newTransformer(unit: global.CompilationUnit) =
    WrapInApiCallTransformer

  val runsAfter: List[String] = List("typer") //since we need the type
  val phaseName: String       = WrapInApiCallComponent.Name

  import global._

  object WrapInApiCallTransformer extends Transformer {
    override def transform(tree: global.Tree) = {
      val transformed = super.transform(tree)
      transformed match {
        case call @ Apply(_, _) =>
          if (call.tpe != null && call.tpe.finalResultType <:< typeOf[
                TypeConstructor[_ <: SpecialElement]]) {
            println(s"Found relevant call $call")

            val typeArguments = call.tpe.typeArgs.map(_.toString).toList

            val listSymbOf = symbolOf[List.type]
            val wrappedFuncSecondArgument =
              q"$listSymbOf.apply(..$typeArguments)"

            val apiObjSymbol = symbolOf[com.example.MyApi.type]

            val wrappedCall =
              q"$apiObjSymbol.process[${call.tpe.finalResultType}]($call, $wrappedFuncSecondArgument)"

            //explicit typing, otherwise later phases throw NPEs etc.
            val ret = typer.typed(wrappedCall)
            println(showRaw(ret))
            println("----")
            ret
          } else {
            call
          }
        case _ => transformed
      }
    }
  }
}

object WrapInApiCallComponent {
  val Name = "api_embed_component"
}
```

This seems to resolve identifiers, as well as types, correctly, outputting e.g.:

```
Apply(TypeApply(Select(TypeTree().setOriginal(Ident(com.example.MyApi)), TermName("process")), List(TypeTree())), List(Apply(TypeApply(Select(Select(Select(Ident(com), com.example), com.example.MyApi), TermName("create")), List(TypeTree())), List(Apply(Select(Ident(com.example.test.Blah), TermName("apply")), List(Literal(Constant("name")))))), Apply(TypeApply(Select(TypeTree().setOriginal(Ident(scala.collection.immutable.List)), TermName("apply")), List(TypeTree())), List(Literal(Constant("com.example.test.Blah"))))))
```

Unfortunately, I get **an error during compilation** starting with:

```
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: 
[error] 
[error]   Unexpected tree in genLoad: com.example.MyApi.type/class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$TypeTree at: RangePosition([projectpath]/testPluginAutoWrap/compiler_plugin_test/src/main/scala/com/example/test/ApiPluginTest.scala, 108, 112, 112)
[error]      while compiling: [projectpath]/testPluginAutoWrap/compiler_plugin_test/src/main/scala/com/example/test/ApiPluginTest.scala
[error]         during phase: jvm
[error]      library version: version 2.12.4
[error]     compiler version: version 2.12.4
[error]   reconstructed args: -Xlog-implicits -classpath [classpath here]
[error] 
[error]   last tree to typer: TypeTree(class String)
[error]        tree position: line 23 of [projectpath]/testPluginAutoWrap/compiler_plugin_test/src/main/scala/com/example/test/ApiPluginTest.scala
```

## QUESTION

It looks I'm screwing something up with type definitions, but what is it?

Specifically:

### How do I correctly wrap every `ExternalApi.createX` call with an `MyApi.process` call, constrained by the requirements provided above?

---

## NOTES

1. Given the amount of boilerplate required, I've set up a complete example project. [**It's available here**](https://github.com/mikolak-net/so_example_meta_wrap).
2. The answer does **not** have to define a compiler plugin. If you're able to cover all the relevant calls with a macro, that is fine as well.
3. Originally the wrapped call was to something like: `def process[T <: TypeConstructor[_ <: SpecialElement] : TypeTag](l: T): T`, the setup here is actually a workaround. So if you are able to generate a wrapped call of this type, i.e. one **that includes a runtime `TypeTag[T]`, that's fine as well**.